# Google Fonts in email signature

Tags: email, google-webfonts

Im using a Google font for an email signature using @import.

The fonts renders very differently on the iphone (maybe other mobile devices too - I dont know). Anyway - it looks very different.

Is this a well known issue? Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Most email clients do not support external stylesheets at all.

Comment: The signature tag should be used for *method* signatures only. I'm guessing this is off topic here, I'm not sure if a single import statement to a style sheet or font counts as programming.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Google fonts is not universal. See this page https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/webfonts/.

Test in Litmus or Email on Acid to see how they render.